# error Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Selenuim

Tags: testing, selenium

I am using Selenium to record my actions on a webpage, however, when I play the test case, there is an click action throwing error: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. However, I am sure that button is visible, and here is html for it:

```
<button class="btn btn-success btnSubmit" style="font-size: 1.9em; width: 100%; height: 2em; margin-top: 20px;" type="submit"> Get Your Report </button>
```

Also, here is my test script for Selenium IDE:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://hra.case.edu/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Get Started</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyPress</td>
    <td>name=searchFirstName</td>
    <td>Tiancheng</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//div[@id='content']//tbody[@id='select_user']/tr[1]//a</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>//div[@id='content']//tbody[@id='select_user']/tr[1]//a</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=answer_heightFoot</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=answer_heightInch</td>
    <td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=answer_weight</td>
    <td>222</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>id=answer_bodySize</td>
    <td>label=Medium</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=answer_diabetes_no</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Other</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=next</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>//button[@type='submit']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>//button[@type='submit']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//button[@type='submit']</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone has an idea of why? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that you have only one `//button[@type='submit']` on page? This could be the problem

Comment: @AlexanderPetrovich thanks for the reply. you are right, there are 2 submit buttons on the page. However, after I switch the Xpath to    .//*[@id='sidebar']/div[1]/button[1], same problem still occurs...

Comment: I guess the html sample you posted in the very beginning is right for that button? If so, try `waitForVisible` method insted of `waitForElementPresent` (if I remember it right, didn't use Selenium IDE quite long). BTW, some of button's ancestors can be invisible at the moment. A bigger html-sample could be handy

Comment: waitForElementPresent actually solved the problem! Thanks man, I really wish i can give you credits... Yes, I am just using IDE to create a basic script and switching to Junit today :) Thank you again.

Comment: Hum, you mean `waitForVisible`, right?

Comment: ...ooops..I paste the wrong one, yes waitForVisible it is!

Comment: If you don't mind I'll post that one as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some webelement may be present at DOM but be invisible at the same time. So, after you perform some action use `waitForVisible` method to wait for element to become visible and interactible

**UPDATE**: @Kees de Kooter, here's the working example

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://stackoverflow.com/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=.js-help-button</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>css=.js-help-button</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForVisible</td>
    <td>css=.js-help-dialog</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is the right answer! I dont have enough reputation to vote now, anyone who is visiting this question, please vote for this one.

Comment: If you put in a proper could sample for `waitForVisible` I will upvote.